# How can I disable the dictionary for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, dictionary

Is there a way to disable the below shown dictionary integration inside Google Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The "Look up" functionality has coverage across the entire operating system, not exclusive to Google Chrome

Comment: True, but it doesn't actually answer the question which is essentially disabling it in Chrome.

Comment: Since it's a macOS feature and Google Chrome doesnt have anything to do with that, no. It is not posible to disable only on Google Chrome.